# Python - How do you print a list item / entry's text instead of its value?

Tags: python, list, printing

e.g.

```
r2 = '192.168.122.72'
r3 = '192.168.122.73'
hostnames = [r2,r3]
#commands = ['term len 0','show run']
for r in hostnames:
    print (r)
    print (hostnames)
    print str(r)
```

Output of this is....

```
192.168.122.72
['192.168.122.72', '192.168.122.73']
192.168.122.72
192.168.122.73
['192.168.122.72', '192.168.122.73']
192.168.122.73
```

I actually want to see an output that will say the items literal text, not its value, so i actually want to see this.......

```
r2
r3
```

Ultimately, want to create a file that is the name of the router, not its IP.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't. Variable names refer to values unidirectionally. Use a dictionary mapping IPs to names (or vice versa) and then iterate over the dicts `items` attribute.

Comment: It is the programmers job to properly organize your code if you want to associate a string to some other value. Variables are not strings, they are source code. You should use a `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You have to use a dictionary for that.

Example:

```
r2 = '192.168.122.72'
r3 = '192.168.122.73'
hostnames = {'r2':r2,'r3':r3}
#commands = ['term len 0','show run']
for r in hostnames:
    print (r)
    print (hostnames)
    print str(r)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I have been able to call either the IP address or the hostname now.